# Reduce/Filter background white noise while recording

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio, audio-recording, noise

I'm trying to figure out a way to filter and reduce white noise while recording audio with my iphone app. Is there a way to at least lower background noise level? Any clue or related libraries are welcome.

Comment: If it's just speech then you can low pass filter without losing quality - that will probably help a little.

Comment: Can you explain how you resolved this issue?

Comment: After searching a lot, I decided to not use filters in my case.. since this problem is solved with the next generation of iphones (>= 4S) with the A5 chip that has a built-in noise cancelling.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a simple noise gate filter, with automatic threshold detection. See:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_gate
- http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid43349351EBEF083D656C8D8DC91A5E2AF51B8609.aspx?s=fft

Comment: thanks man, noise gate is really good for voice recording, but when you try to use it with music or something else it isnt the same. I think my goal is apply a lowpass filter, even if my audio loses a little of quality the noise effect is reduced a lot